# django_mongodb_engine ImproperlyConfigured

Tags: django, mongodb, django-mongodb-engine

I am trying to setup the environment for Django+MongDB+Mongodbengine. However, I am still getting the error,

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django_mongodb_engine'
>   isn't an available database backend.

I use following command to start the server:

```
Start server: python3 manage.py runserver
```

I have Python 2.7.10 in the virtual environment, and my requirement.txt is:

```
Django==1.7.11 
djangotoolbox==1.8.0 
mongoengine==0.13.0 
pymongo==2.8
pyserial==3.1.1 
requests==2.13.0 
six==1.10.0 
wheel==0.24.0
```

**Manager.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "backend_server.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Here is the setting.py

```
"""
Django settings for backend_server project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'w50tc+keeha_&9^i1n!++y-k-1h@ob58#^1we8z2v5o$b(*9e%'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'backend_server.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backend_server.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE' : 'django_mongodb_engine',
        'NAME' : 'mydatabase'

    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I have searched on the internet for solutions, but didn't get one. Is there any problem with versions?
How should I correct them?

Comment: use  : `python manage.py runserver`. Since you are using Python 2.7.x and you are running command python3 to run server.

Comment: There will be syntax errors in manager.py if I run python, so weird

Comment: paste you error.

Comment: File "manage.py", line 14
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Could you post the full stack trace and the `manage.py` file content?

Comment: Just updated, please have a check.

Comment: can you post your settings for database configurations? also check if you have your virtualenv activated.

Comment: virtualenv is activated, but I am messed up with versions, I think there should be a problem with version somethere, thanks guys.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is that I transfer the website to MEAN Stack, I think it's a good platform for MongoDB. However, if someone find the version solution for Mongoengine stuffs, welcome to post your answers, thanks.